# Maintain aspect ratio with ffmpeg for television format

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to capture screen images into a pipe in ffmpeg and create a video.
This is how it works:

```
-f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=48000:cl=stereo -f image2pipe -r 25 -i pipe: -target pal-dv25 -vcodec dvvideo -vf yadif=1:-1:0,interlace=bff,setdar=1.85:1 -flags +ildct+ilme -c:a pcm_s16le -maxrate 5000k -r 25 -f mov -shortest -map 0:a -map 1:v -y out.mov
```

The problem is that the images have a 16:9 resolution and I get [16:9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkhPX.jpg) in original_aspect_ratio line in Mediainfo with dar=1.85:1 but I need [4:3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCbYU.jpg) also with dar=1.85:1.

How can I achieve this? I tried to change ratio of input images with `-aspect 4:3` but this leads to the resolution of the video be only 4:3 without dar=1.85:1

Comment: What difference does it make?

Comment: I suppose it is related to sar, par and dar and tv will show my video incorrectly

Comment: SAR/PAR and DAR are interdependent, So, for a given DAR, there can only be one SAR which the setdar filter will set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to scale input video to be 4:3 ratio and then set DAR to be 1.85, ffmpeg will choose SAR automatically to match this parameters. This is how your filter should look:

```
scale=4/3*ih:ih,setdar=1.85
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it didn`t help. I looked in metadata of correct file and it has 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 28800 kb/s, SAR 35:24 DAR 175:96

And my file after your command has this data
720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 28800 kb/s, SAR 37:25 DAR 37:20

Comment: It looks like -target pal-dv25 overrides all the other options, because no matter what source I use and what scale and dar I set, result is always 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], and dvvideo codec works with only limited amount of resolution. I think your best bet is to [try to ask ffmpeg](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/mailman/listinfo/ffmpeg-user/) directly @Elmo